# Create a repeating binary pattern of known length

Tags: python-3.x, binary

I want to create a repeating binary pattern based on a user-specified length.  The number specified would determine the number of 0's and 1's in each cycle.  For example, if the user inputs 2, then they would get `0011`.  If the user inputs 8, they would get `0000000011111111`.  Here's my problem... I can create the binary string using the format method, but only because I know the length and hardcode the format.

```
def togglePattern(iLength):
    """ set up a repeating pattern """
    ones = 1

    for i in range(0, iLength):
         ones = ones | (1 << i)

    dnup = '{:016b}'.format(ones)
    print("dnup: %s" % dnup)
```

If I pass in a length of 8 I get this:

```
updn: 0000000011111111
```

But if I pass in a 2, then I get this, obviously:

```
updn: 0000000000000011
```

How do I get it to format that string at twice the 'iLength'?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
numbits = 8
print(numbits * '1' + numbits * '0')
```

Comment: Python is pretty wonderful that way, once you get to know it.